# Is there a musical term for melodic density?

Tags: terminology

Is there a musical term for melodic density? By density i simply mean the amount of melodic (as opposed to harmonic) notes within a given time measure.

Example: 40 notes within a bar has higher melodic density than 10 notes within a bar.

(I realize tempo is also a factor for perceived density).

Comment: It feels like the definition misses harmony vs melody, it could be a single 40 note chord.

Comment: I see your point, but i did write *melodic* density. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Compulsory YouTube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUFwk1Ibwkc

Comment: @Tetsujin There can **never** be too many notes

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a comparison to digital communications. Bandwidth = number of notes per second, maybe? Similar concept to data rate such as kbps.

Answer (score 1):

**Melodic density**, while not a "term of art", would be generally understood to mean as you intend.

In 1962, Milton Babbitt coined the term ***time-point interval***, which can be used to describe the linear density of pitch onsets. A ***time point*** is the instantaneous moment at which a note begins (its ***onset***). The *time-point interval* is the distance between onsets. It can be measured according to note-values rather than absolute time, and thus is tempo-independent.

For example, in 4/4 time, a quarter note followed by a quarter rest and then a half note would have a time-point interval (also called ***interonset interval***) of a half note — the time from the initiation of the first quarter note to the initiation of the half note. An eighth note followed by a dotted quarter rest and then a half note would also have a time-point interval of a half note.

Thus, a measure with 40 linear (melodic) onsets would have a higher average interonset interval (call it ***interonset density***) than a measure with 10 linear onsets.